# For given odd prime $q$, does there exist a prime $p$ such that $q$ is a primitive root mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Artin's conjecture  says that for any non-squre positive integer $n$, there exist infinitely many prime $p$ such that $n$ is a primitive root mod $p$. So, what can we said about existence of one prime.